# What does an assignment do if it is within square messaging brackets?

Tags: objective-c

In some old(ish) Objective-C code base, I accidentally misplaced the opening bracket trying to send a message to an object.

```
// I meant to type object = [object someEncodingMethod]
[object = object someEncodingMethod];
```

This compiles and runs just fine, but after this line the original `object` variable is not modified. The actual code is trivial to fix, but I'm very curious what this line even *means*.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing particularly fancy going on. You've assigned the value of `object` to the variable `object`, and then sent a message to that value. The return value of the called method is thrown away.

I believe *any* expression that, to the compiler, looks like it evaluates to an object type is legal in the sender position of a message send. And in C, an assignment is an expression that evaluates to the assigned value. (Compare, for example, `if( 0 != (result = makeABox()) )`, or closer to home `if(( self = [super init] ))`.)

Comment: To clarify a bit: `object = object` is a sub-expression of the larger message-send expression and does the same thing there that it does anywhere else. It's an assignment, but effectively a no-op and equivalent to if you just had put `object` there.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense.